# How to display output on Java Frame load?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, gui-builder

I think they removed the windowOpened event in Netbeans 8.0. I have to display the output of some input which I took in the previous frame on loading of this frame. How do I do this?

You can see it doesn't exist anymore. I can't post image with this reputation. So I am giving a link of my Facebook account.

[image]

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/2587435)

Comment: Try and click on the properties tab to the right, and select events at the top. See if its there. I'm not sure about 8.0. I'm still on 7.4

Comment: That's really interesting post. I liked tabbed pane idea but I need it for project and u know how the faculties are. What they want they want.

So....

Comment: Nope..! Not even there.
Relly missing 7.4. I had it earlier. Upgraded just a week ago.

Comment: You can always just hand code it

Comment: It's hard to tell, but you may not have clicked on the frame, where the event can be registered...click the form element in the navigator window and check the events tab in the properties window

Comment: I solved it. A small problem was there. Took me 2 hrs to find out. But solved now..!

Comment: Would you like to share? Post an answer :-)

Comment: *"What they want they want."*  Tell them *"fine, so long as you're prepared to pay twice the price (it will take twice as long to get it minimally workable) for a flawed product"*.  Report back if they still 'insist' on paying twice the price for a flawed product.

Comment: Ha ha @AndrewThompson
I'll surely tell them.

Comment: BTW, the mistake here is I had by mistake used jPanel instead of jFrame as you people can see in the navigator pane. Now if somebody can please rate this question at least 1 or 2, I would be very happy. Because my asking questions privilege has been removed since my last question which was genuine was rated -2 and this 0.

Please........!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Perhaps you'd get more up votes if you posted code (your best attempt to solve the problem) instead of screen shots of the IDE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson If I do that, this whole page would be filled up with code only. Its 200 lines of code.

Comment: 200 LOC can be an MCVE if all 200 LOC is *actually* necessary to display the problem.  But be sure it is.  It isn't if 120 LOC of code is that verbose GUI builder crap.  It isn't if 10 code lines are used to (unnecessarily) set a PLAF.  And as an aside, it won't 'fill the page'.  Code areas offer scroll bars.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ya ya....
That's fine. But bow that I have told the answer, will you please up vote my question???

Comment: Because now I get this:
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: I won't, for two reasons.  1) It is still not a good question.  2) I don't think up or down votes has anything to do with being prevented from voting. -- You keep mentioning 'See help center' but failing to mention what it said about the cause.  What was the copy/pasted cause? -- One way to help *might* be to write up your solution as an answer, enter it, and accept it.  Having *accepted* answers might help.  And who knows, perhaps the answer will be good enough that I (and other people) up vote it.